# EF6: efficient way to search for a name in an IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm writing an application that has a search bar that allows users to search for people by their name - **First Name, Middle name, and Last Name**

Search input can either be First Name or  middle name or last name. Or a combination of First and name; First and Middle name and so on....

Or the Full name.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
 var result = People.Where(e => e.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(model.Name.ToLower()) || e.LastName.ToLower().Contains(model.Name.ToLower()) || e.MiddleName.ToLower().Contains(model.Name.ToLower()));
```

I'm wondering is this the most efficient way or can it be improved?

Comment: when you say that search input can only be the middle name, then why do you compare it with Firstname, and last name in your where clause?

Comment: not just the middle name, it can be a combination of either First, Middle, and last name or the full name. I updated the question.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Marco Alves* said you can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) library this way:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<People>();
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName))
   predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.FirstName.Contains(model.FirstName));
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LastName))
   predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.LastName.Contains(model.LastName));
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.MiddleName))
   predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.MiddleName.Contains(model.MiddleName));

var result = context.People.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which allows you to control the AND's and OR's of the where statement easier.

There's also [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which allows you to submit the WHERE clause like a SQL string and it will parse it into the correct predicate for a WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider concatenating all your names and checking for `IndexOf(input) > -1`

```
var result = People.Where(e => 
      (e.FirstName + " " + e.MiddleName + " " + e.LastName).IndexOf(model.Name) > -1);
```